# Discard changes in PHP server when aborting HTTP connection from Android

Tags: php, android, http

I'm working on an Android app that uses HttpsUrlConnection class to comunicate with a Apache/PHP/MySQL server.
When I want to abort the connection, I call `connection.disconnect()`,
but on the server side the process is already done and populated via Push to other Android devices.

So, how can I stop the process if the connection is closed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `ignore_user_abort(false);` and constantly check for connection status in php code using

```
if(connection_aborted()){
  //stop processing here
}
```

Give a read on this. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php

If the server has completed and populated via push then you can do anything about it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try.  But, when the app starts the connection, I show a ProgressDialog with a cancel button. So, that button is useless when the server has completed and I receive the response. It only works if the process is not done yet. Is there some way to avoid this? I mean having a button that is useless after the middle of the whole procress.